# Net::ReadTimeout exception is always thrown while connecting to a particular network

Tags: ruby, security, firewall, watir-webdriver, network-security

I'm writing test scripts in Ruby Watir. I work in two networks - let's say home and office network.

While running in office network, it is always throwing 'Net::ReadTimeout' exception but in home network, it works fine. (Both provide same speed - Infact, office network is better than home network)

Is it something related to firewall settings in office network which is making to throw this error always?

Comment: It's very likely that this has something to do with the network, not Ruby or Watir. Did you try to ping the host that gives you a time out? Did you try to connect to the URL via browser or curl?

Comment: Connecting through browser to the URL works fine. Only invoking through script says this timeout

Comment: Without knowing the code and the URLs it's hard to say what is going wrong.